# Compile with clang instead of gcc

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, clang

I have downloaded `openssh-6.4p1` for Linux and I want to compile it using `clang` instead of `gcc`. How can I tell the compilation engine to do this? Do I need to modify `configure`?

Comment: Run:  `CC=clang ./configure ...`

Comment: That works, but how can I keep the generated LLVM modules during the process?

Comment: I don't know much about LLVM.  I don't know of any way to do it, unless LLVM can build both the .o file and the module file in the same command.  If it can, you can add extra arguments to the compile line to force that using CFLAGS.  E.g., `CC=clang CFLAGS='-emit-llvm' ./configure`.  If you have to run LLVM separately, once to get the object and again for the module, then it's likely there's no way to do it without major changes to the build environment, because you have to get a completely new set of rules.

Comment: I just want to get the IR representation of each C source file so I can perform analysis on the IR. After I analyze it, I want to then compile all the IR files to native code.

Comment: Will that compile just IR files or will it compile binaries and leave the IR files there as well? I'm not sure I'm understanding the instructions.

Comment: @RouteMapper, with `-flto` all the object files will be in IR. There is also a linker option (if you're using `gold`) to keep the combined IR module as well, e.g., `-Wl,-plugin-opt=also-emit-llvm`

Comment: The combined IR module being one big object file, I take it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the option command like this:

```
option(USE_CLANG "build application with clang" ON) # OFF is the default
```

and then you can wrap the clang-compiler settings in the if() condition like this:

```
if(USE_CLANG)
    SET (...)
    //...
endif(USE_CLANG)
```

Comment: Do you know how I can also tell clang to emit LLVM modules during the compilation process? Normally, one would compile a C source file to LLVM using `clang -emit-llvm somefile.c -S -o somefile.ll`.

Comment: I don't really understand how to you use this answer ? Where should I write this option command ?